# Is there an out of the box Flexviewer set up for a Flex Mobile Project?

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer

**Question:**
Is there an out of the box Flexviewer set up for a Flex Mobile Project?

**Background:**
I could just create a Flex Mobile AIR Project from one the samples that ESRI supplies, but that would require a bit more work to recreate an app that is based upon ESRI's ArcGIS Viewer.

**Asked Here Initially:**
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/33387-Flex-Viewer-for-Mobile-Applications?p=215235#post215235

**Flexviewer Github Page:**
https://github.com/ArcGIS/ArcGISViewerForFlex

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't an out-of-the-box FlexViewer for use with a Flex Mobile project.